# Angular 2 *ngFor issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

After updating Angular 2 to RC.5 some stranfge error appear:

```
TypeError: changes.forEachOperation is not a function
```

and it points to the html part which looks like:

```
<ion-list>
  <button ion-item menuClose *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
    <ion-icon item-left [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
    {{ p.title | translate }}
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

and which is initialized by such code inside the component:

```
pages: PageObj[] = [
{ title: "dashboard.Title", component: DashboardPage, icon: "calendar" },
{ title: "transactions.Title", component: TransactionsPage, icon: "cash" },
{ title: "categories.Title", component: CategoriesPage, icon: "pricetags" },
{ title: "budgets.Title", component: BudgetsPage, icon: "briefcase" },
{ title: "personal.Title", component: PersonalPage, icon: "ios-person" }
// { title: "cards.Title", component: CardsPage, icon: "ios-person" }
```

];

there is also an interface for PageObj.
Strangest things about this are that:

1. It was working with RC.3
2. Same code is working in Ionic Conference App example.

Comment: Could you please add that code in a plunker like [this one](https://plnkr.co/edit/vKgkOF?p=info) so we can test it?. It uses the latest Ionic 2 beta.11 version together with Angular RC4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compared code and libs in my project and in ionic-conference-app latest example and found out that I was using

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/forms": "0.3.0"
```

and after replacing it with

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0"
```

everything is working fine